# Compact groups are Moore groups

Tags: locally-compact-groups

A locally compact group $G$ is said to be a Moore group if each irreducible continuous unitary representation of $G$ is finite dimensional.

I'm trying to see why a compact group $G$ would be a Moore group.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this just (one form of) the Peter-Weyl theorem?

Comment: I think you are right. I didn't know about this theorem.

Comment: @anomaly is there an analogue for Peter-Weyl theorem for semigroups?

Comment: It doens't hold as stated for semigroups, but there are some results in that direction; I don't know the details.